# Removing loops in a graph network

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I've a Networkx graph like displayed in the following image

[image]

The image has been created using the code below

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=20, m=30, seed=1)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
G.add_edges_from([(2, 20), (20, 8)])
n = len(G.nodes())

retain_node_ids = [1,2]
G.add_edges_from([(u, v) for u in retain_node_ids for v in (n, n+1)])
G = nx.k_core(G, k=2)
G.remove_nodes_from([n, n+1])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

This is a flow network and I want to remove loops like the one marked in red. This is a sample graph; in the real networks there are many loops like this and I want to detected and delete all the edges from such loops.

[image]

For instance, the flow direction is from 7 -> 8 and there is no exit, edge (7,8) is not a multiedge.

Suggestions on how to remove such loops will be really appreciated.

EDIT:
Why do I want to delete the loop region inside red box?
It's because the graph is directed. Let's consider the flow direction is from 7 to 8 and this is a transport network, once the consignment flows into 8 then it can be transported from 8 -> 2 or 8-> 20 but there is no exit from the loop.

Comment: Sounds like you want to calculate a [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).

Comment: Is your graph directed? I assume it is because you're talking about a flow, if yes, what is the starting node? Are you only interested in finding the isolated loops (connected to the rest of the graph only by 1 edge)?

Comment: @AzimMazinani Yes, my graph is directed

Comment: @Oil L Thanks for the suggestion. But I am looking for a way to remove only the loops like mentioned above, minimum spanning tree will remove the other loops too.

Comment: @Natasha how do you define loop? Why `3-5-13-17-7-14-15` is not a loop? Is loop is only consecutive ascending numbers?

Comment: @AvivYaniv I'm referring to the edges present in the red box as loop

Comment: Sure @Natasha, I mean why them specifically (just because there is only one vertex connected to the "other" part of the graph?)

Comment: @AvivYaniv Could you please have a look at my edit? I hope I was able to answer your question. Kindly let me know if it is still not explained well

Comment: The question is ill-formed. What makes the loop in the red box different from any other loop in the graph? The presented graph is also undirected, but the question seems to be concerned with a specific loop pattern in a directed graph? At least post a directed graph that clearly shows what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Tarjan's algorithm detects loops in a directed graph, and reports the nodes caught in the loop.  Depending on implementation you'd have to re-run it multiple times until it came clean.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the loop that I want to delete has only 3 nodes( also illustrated above). It is not clear to me how Tarjan's algorithm can be used here. Could you please elaborate on this?